# Django 1.5 graph extensions -x option ignored

Tags: django, graphviz, pygraphviz

I use `django-extensions` to visualize my database structure of my Django project (Django Version 1.5) with the command `python manage.py graph_models my_model -x user -o output.png`.

Unfortunately, after upgrading to Django 1.5, graph_models ignores the option `-x`. This option can be used to exclude models from the graph.

Since I have the `user` model in almost all models in my Django app, it is important for me to exclude the user from the graph. Otherwise the graph becomes too full and hard to read.

I would be thankful for any suggestions on how to work around that.

Comment: I know it's just a workaround, but have you tried producing a dot file instead and using `twopi`, having the user model inside a circle? Maybe it will be good enough for your needs…

Answer (score 3):

I realized that this had nothing to do with Django 1.5.

What I had to do replace the `-x` option with the capitalized `-X` option. The first is to exclude columns, the second to exclude models. What I did is rename the column (model field) from `user` to `creator` and so the column name did not match anymore and thus appeared on the graph again.

I found that difference in the options for the `graph_models` in the [django-extensions github repository](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/management/commands/graph_models.py).

The command that worked in the end is the following:

`python manage.py graph_models mymodel1 mymodel2 -g -X User -o mygraph.png`

Comment: Nice, one can exclude multiple models with -X ModelA,ModelB